# JavaScript and JQuery card game, I want to stop after 5 cards drawn and clear score to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I have this code from my teacher that I have changed the scores of the cards to reflect their value, but for this simple game I just want the player to only be able to draw 5 cards, then the score resets. It will be a two player game of luck on who gets the higher score in 5 cards. please Help with drawing only 5 cards, and resetting the score to 0. Thank You!

```
 <script>
     // set score
     var score = 0;

     // create card deck object
     var cardDeck = $("#cardtray").playingCards();

     // shuffle card objects
     cardDeck.shuffle();

     function playRound() {
        // draw one card object from deck
        var card = cardDeck.draw();

        // log card object to browser console for observing
        console.log( card );



            // a nested if statement
            if ( card.rank == 'K' ) {
                score = score + 10;
            }

            if ( card.rank == 'Q' ) {
                score = score + 10;
            }

            if ( card.rank == 'J' ) {
                score = score + 10;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '10' ) {
                score = score + 10;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '9' ) {
                score = score + 9;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '8' ) {
                score = score + 8;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '7' ) {
                score = score + 7;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '6' ) {
                score = score + 6;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '5' ) {
                score = score + 5;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '4' ) {
                score = score + 4;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '3' ) {
                score = score + 3;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '2' ) {
                score = score + 2;
            }

            if ( card.rank == 'A' ) {
                score = score + 1;
            }





            // control for score floor at zero
            if ( score < 0 ) {
            score = 0;
            }

            // output score
            $('#scoreboard').html( score );

            // output html for card drawn
            var markup = card.getHTML();
            $('#cardtray').html( markup );
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable to store the card draw count, when it reaches 5, you can display the total score and reset the draw counter and the score to 0.

```
<script>
     // set score
     var score = 0;

     var draws=0;

     // create card deck object
     var cardDeck = $("#cardtray").playingCards();

     // shuffle card objects
     cardDeck.shuffle();

     function playRound(player) {
        // draw one card object from deck
        var card = cardDeck.draw();

        // log card object to browser console for observing
        console.log( card );



            // a nested if statement
            if ( card.rank == 'K' ) {
                score = score + 10;
            }

            if ( card.rank == 'Q' ) {
                score = score + 10;
            }

            if ( card.rank == 'J' ) {
                score = score + 10;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '10' ) {
                score = score + 10;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '9' ) {
                score = score + 9;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '8' ) {
                score = score + 8;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '7' ) {
                score = score + 7;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '6' ) {
                score = score + 6;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '5' ) {
                score = score + 5;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '4' ) {
                score = score + 4;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '3' ) {
                score = score + 3;
            }

            if ( card.rank == '2' ) {
                score = score + 2;
            }

            if ( card.rank == 'A' ) {
                score = score + 1;
            }





            // control for score floor at zero
            if ( score < 0 ) {
            score = 0;
            }

            // output score
            $('#scoreboard').html( score );

            // output html for card drawn
            var markup = card.getHTML();
            $('#cardtray').html( markup );

        //We add 1 one draw
         draws++;
        //If we reached the 5 cards, we reset the score.
         if(draws==5){
           console.log("Total score: "+score);
           score=0;
           //We reset the draws
           draws=0;
         }


        }
    </script>
```

You can also use a for loop, but since you are learning, i dont know if you are allowed yet.